# How yarn application id is generated

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I kick off a yarn application, it gives the id as `application_1560618551799_4465795`

But, I am supprised to find that 1560618551799 means `Sun Jun 16 01:09:11 CST 2019`,which is about 3 months ago.

I have thought that the timestamp in the id will fall into today, I would ask whether I am able to figure out when the application kicks off from id?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, application start time can't be deduced from the application ID itself. [Source code for the `ApplicationId`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-3.2.0-RC1/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-api/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationId.java#L28) provides the following narrative:

> `ApplicationId` represents the **globally unique** identifier for an
>   application.
>
> The globally unique nature of the identifier is
>   achieved by using the 
>   **cluster timestamp** i.e. start-time of the  `ResourceManager` along with a monotonically increasing counter for the application

You'll probably need to [`getApplicationReport`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html#getApplicationReport-org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ApplicationId-) using `YarnClient`, and extract start time from there.